Event-based trigger based on cross-tenant storage events
I need to define a trigger where my ADF pipeline in Tenant A would be triggered each time a blob is uploaded to storage account in Tenant B. What would be the ideal endpoint type to use? I'm exploring Azure Function, Webhook or Event Hub Namespace Topic.
